# Response of api call in subscribe callback prints different than what i see in network tab

Tags: angular, http

I made an HTTP request using @angular/common/http and this is the response in the network
[image]

I put a console log in the code like this:

```
    this.apiService.get('company').subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log('Response Data: ', res);
    });
```

the Response data is this:

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "data": {
        "Id": 13,
        "NameEn": "",
        "NameAr": "",
        "StatusId": 1,
        "Logo": "",
        "Address": "",
        "Email": "monther.amer48+12@gmail.com",
        "POBox": "",
        "Fax": "",
        "Phone": "+9625980214555",
        "Website": "",
        "Location": null,
        "UserId": 72,
        "CountryId": 14,
        "CityId": null,
        "CreatedBy": 72,
        "CreatedDate": "2022-02-13T13:22:19.810Z",
        "ModifiedBy": null,
        "ModifiedDate": "2022-02-13T13:40:11.707Z",
        "DeletedBy": null,
        "DeletedDate": null
    },
    "error": null,
    "status": 200
}
```

Anyone has any Idea why the CityId value changed from 6 to null

Comment: check your http interceptor probably

Comment: @AakashGarg this is my interceptor
```
  get<TResponse>(uri: string, params = new HttpParams(), headers = new HttpHeaders()): Observable<TResponse> {
    return this.http.get<TResponse>(this.baseUrl + uri, { headers, params }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is `this.apiService`? Maybe some mapping is happening there